# How can start Service several times while Service is alive

Tags: android, service, android-service

I want to do this acts with my Service :

1)start App

3)start a Service by App

4)update my UI by Service

5)close App but the Service keep work

6)sart App again

7)connect to Service (not run new Service)

[image]

I want in my service public variable during living Service do not change.

Comment: are you using a bound `Service`?

Comment: yes David WAsser

Comment: Then i am confused by your fiagram. Are you calling `startService()`, or `stopService()` or `bindService()`. What are you trying to do and what is your problem?

Comment: i use start service and bound service to test my  idea.

Comment: OK. Then what exactly is your problem? Your question is not clear. What isn't working as expected or what do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

If you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` then your `Service` will run unstil it is explicitly stopped. You can then decide how you want to stop your `Service`, either by something calling `stopService()` or by the `Service` calling `stopSelf()` when it no longer wants to run.

Please also note that Android can kill your `Service` pretty much whenever it wants to. If you have returned `START_STICKY` then Android will restart your `Service` after it kills it, but there is nothing you can do to ensure that Android will not kill your `Service`.